# can't understand code about go's print function

Tags: go

i am new to golang, when i read the code example of package "archtive/tar",i read some code like this:

```
// Iterate through the files in the archive.
for {
hdr, err := tr.Next()
    if err == io.EOF {
        // end of tar archive
        break
    }
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Contents of %s:\n", hdr.Name)
    if _, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, tr); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

the output just like this:

```
Contents of readme.txt:
This archive contains some text files.
Contents of gopher.txt:
Gopher names:
George
Geoffrey
Gonzo
Contents of todo.txt:
Get animal handling license.
```

can anyone tell me how the programe print the body of the struct? thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You left out a vital piece of the example, the two lines preceding what you posted.

```
// Open the tar archive for reading.
r := bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes())
tr := tar.NewReader(r)
```

This creates a `tar.Reader` which implements `io.Reader`. The statement `io.Copy(os.Stdout, tr)` in the `if` statement knows how to copy the contents of the reader to `Stdout`.

[Godoc for `tar.Reader`](https://godoc.org/archive/tar#Reader)

Also might be useful to note that the code example in the package documentation doesn't ever write the tar it creates to disk. It is all done in memory using `bytes.Buffer`s. Examples of writing to disk would be in the `io` package.